# How in PyQt5 load QLabel from another class?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Probably, I miss a basic thing. I am trying to load QLabel class from another file to my main Widget file and I fail.

file **label_class.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys, math

class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, armnumber):
        super(Label,self).__init__(self, parent=None)

        self.armnumber = armnumber
        self.propDia = 16
        self.line = self.createLines(self.armnumber)[0]
        self.points = self.createLines(self.armnumber)[1]
        self.circle = self.createEllipse(self.propDia, self.points)
```

file **polygon.py**

```
import sys, math
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from label_class import Label

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(400,400,400,400)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.label = Label(8)

app = QApplication(sys.argv) 

widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get the following error

```
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type Label was never called
```

I miss a tiny thing, please help!

Comment: Change `super(Label,self).__init__(self, parent=None)` to `super(Label,self).__init__(parent=None)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain what the exact difference is, please?

Comment: When you use `super(Label, self)` you are calling the parent constructor, and you must pass the parameters you want, and in this case, you can receive a parent.